# How to dispatch routes from controllers?

Tags: laravel, routes, dispatch

In the most PHP framework there is a dispatcher to dispatch a route that is indeed essential. e.g.

- https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html
- https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Dispatcher.html

Is there any similar thing in Laravel?

> dispatching `!=` redirecting

Comment: You could have a look at the ControllerDispatcher (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L37), but I'm honestly not sure if it works the way you ask for. Hopefully it's of some help anyway. :)

Comment: can you explain in which use case is this route dispatching useful?

Comment: @lewis4u You can consider it as a redirect but not via http, it redirect is done internally.

Comment: I need more info. For example from a users perspective. What does the user see? What happens actually?

Comment: @lewis4u Google is your friend in general consepts: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=route+dispating+mvc+php

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L494

Comment: @AnitaYip No, it is not. The function need to receive controller and action name. `$this->dispatch('FooControoller@bar')` .

Comment: `dispatch` function in turn invokes `dispatchToRoute` which gets the route based on the request information (url and method). The route contains the information about the controller method to be invoked. You can further dig into this function to see how the request is dispatched to the controller via _middleware_ in the function `runRouteWithinStack`